# How to change the camera from Landscape to Portrait

Tags: camera

I need a way to render a picture that is longer heighth-wise than width-wise.
Changing the scale of the camera does nothing. I've been told to look in the scene focus settings, and I didn't see anything.
Is there a way to change the shape of the rendered image?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to do this is to swap the values for the `x` and `y` resolution fields of the camera Dimensions-Resolution section. So, for instance, change it from 1920x1080 to 1080x1920.

[image]

For 2.8 the resolution settings are in Properties > Output > Resolution

[image]

The other way I know of is to select the camera and, while viewing from it, rotating the camera 90 degrees. This, however, rotates the view too.

Comment: I would refer to those as the resolution of the "scene" since the top of the subsection is "Scene".  So instead of 1920x1080, make it 1080x1920.

Comment: But it says "Scene" for all tabs

Comment: You're half-right.  A great many of those tabs do say Scene at the top.  I was able to find some (the object tab for example) that did not.

Comment: Still, not a good way to identify them